# Accessibility: select tag title

Tags: android, html, drop-down-menu, accessibility, android-a11y

I'm trying to define a title for a `<select>` tag which is read by the Android screen reader, mostly called "Talkback". On my test device (Galaxy S8+) it's called "Voice Assistant".

Interestingly, the following HTML works with NVDA (PC) and with VoiceOver (iOS), but I don't have any idea why it doesn't work on Android.

Here's the minimal example as HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        form{
            background: red;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
        label,
        select{
            display: block;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/test">Test link</a>
<form action="/en" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <label name="edit-destination-1-label" id="edit-destination-1-label" for="edit-destination-1">Choose language</label>
    <select id="edit-destination-1" name="edit-destination-1" aria-labelledby="edit-destination-1-label">
        <option value="/de">German</option>
        <option value="/fr">French</option>
        <option value="/en" selected="selected">English</option>
    </select>
</form>
<a href="/test">Test link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it's just a reference of `for` and `id` as well as a reference of `aria-labelledby`.

Does anyone know a solution here? I just want the Android screen reader to speak "Choose language" and when you activate it, it should jump to the select menu.

For a working example reference take the [post.ch page](https://www.post.ch/en/private), section "calculate prices". When you navigate to it with Android it reads "Country" before the `<select>`.

**EDIT** What I've done to solve the problem temporary is to use a link instead of a label, as this works.

Comment: How does it behave when you remove `aria-labelledby`?

Comment: Doesn't change something.